# How to change camera view with respect to the current axes coordinate system in Matlab

Tags: matlab, figure

In 3D system I want the camera to look at x-y plane so that the camera optical axis is along the z axis and the principal point is (0,0). How can I do this?
Or say before I change the camera pos and angle( rotation) I want to same the extrinsic parameters( pos and rotation) and then to be able to restore them and move the camera to where originally was.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Matlab docs on setting camera properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f4-44406.html).

You get and set these properties (`CameraPosition` is one, `CameraTarget` is another) the usual way:

```
oldpos = get(gca,'CameraPosition');

newpos = [0 0 10];#%positioned at z=10
target = [0 0 0];#%aimed at the origin
set(gca,'CameraPosition',newpos,'CameraTarget',target);
```

You will have to play around with these settings (and maybe others) to get your desired results.  Everything you need to know is in the documentation.